# How to know if the coffee at the office is freshly brewed?

Tags: professionalism

At our office, we have nice coffee makers and unlimited Starbucks coffee beans. The problem is, I'm just not sure when the coffee was brewed. Was it brewed yesterday? A few hours ago? Do I have to empty the pot and brew a fresh one? What is the proper procedure here?

Comment: Have you other colleagues you can ask? Maybe they have an unwritten process for topping up the brewed coffee.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Navigating the Workplace, and is more about coffee... perhaps  it would better fit [Coffee.SE](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @DarkCygnus Man there’s a site for every topic, this network is amazing!

Comment: @ChrisCirefice jajajajaja and remember there's Area 51 if you want to suggest a new one! :D

Answer (score 8):

I my office we attached a very small whiteboard and pen to the wall beside the coffee pot. Whenever anyone starts a brew they write the time on the whiteboard. Then it is easy to know how fresh the coffee. It is at everyone's discretion whether they drink old coffee or throw it out and start a new pot. The only rule we have is that if you empty the pot you start a new one. We work regular office hours and make coffee often enough to know that "9:30" this morning and not yesterday.

You could start even simpler than this. A stack of post-it notes and a pen could work. You don't even need to put up rules. Simply stick a note on the coffee machine with the time you made the coffee. Others will probably follow your lead.

Answer (score 6):

If it's a bean-to-cup machine, then it's mostly freshly ground and brewed.

We have these at my office.

Basically, for fresh brewed coffee, you're looking for [crema](http://www.coffeegeek.com/opinions/barista/10-14-2006) - the fine foam that you get on top of black coffee that's a light tan colour.

When I get my coffee, I check for this.  If it's just flat black water, I'll tip it away and get a fresh cup out of the machine and I'll invariably get the crema on the second cup.

If you get latte or cappuccino out of the machine, then think again about what you're doing with your life - the milk in these machines is invariably dried powder and therefore pretty nasty (if you like coffee).  Avoid this, if you value the taste of your coffee.

If you have a filter machine that dispenses into the carafe, then take a look at the filter (if you can) - are those grounds still warm and moist?  If you can't get to the filter, just take the carafe away and give the machine a good sniff - does it smell of freshly brewed coffee?

Also, think carefully before you throw away a nearly full carafe of coffee, people might see this as being wasteful.

If in doubt, go with the taste.  If you're happy, drink it - if it tastes of warm black water, throw it away and brew some more.

Comment: fwiw, I've usually heard crema in the context of espresso or Moka Express. Most generic/industrial drip coffee machines are going to give you flat black water. Its only saving grace is usually that it's hot. If the coffee smells burned (and it's on a hot plate) or is cold, that's a pretty good indicator that it's time for a new pot.

Comment: @mcknz that is correct. Crema occurs during the espresso extraction process. It is a product of the amount of pressure required to push the water through the ground espresso and the temperature of the water. For this reason, you will not see crema on percolated coffee. But you may see a little bit when using a single serve coffee machine as there is some pressure build up.

Comment: You don't want to be the guy the jacks up the coffee.